# Setting Git commit SHA as an environment variable using Azure's webapps-deploy GitHub Action

Tags: azure, github, github-actions, action

I'd like to set the current GitHub commit SHA as an environment variable when deploying my application using `webapps-deploy`: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy

How can I achieve this?

My current yaml looks something like this:

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions
# More info on Python, GitHub Actions, and Azure App Service: https://aka.ms/python-webapps-actions

name: My App Deployment Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: '3.9'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          python -m playwright install

      - name: Build Project
        run: |
          cd frontend
          npm ci
          npm run build

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/
            !frontend/node_modules/
          retention-days: 5

  deploy-staging:
    name: Deploy to staging
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'stage'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'my-app-name'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.publishprofile }}
          

  deploy-production:
    name: Deploy to production
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build, deploy-staging]
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'my-app-name'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.publishprofile }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code to to set Commit SHA environment variable and it worked successfully in Python Azure Web app github action workflow.

**My github action workflow:-**

You can refer the complete workflow code [**here**](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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).

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - valleywebapp0

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.9'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Set Commit SHA environment variable
        run:   echo "COMMIT_SHA=${GITHUB_SHA}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
         
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .
          
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'valleywebapp0'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_FBE0A8A87E804D00802E7E91678FC5E5 }}
```

**Output:-**

[image]